# OutofMemory Error in C# in TIF file

Tags: c#

when more then 1366 file scan after that it will raise an error
the code count the tif file on selected folder
Code:

```
 int mergeTiffPages(string[] path)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        string[] sa = path;
        int frame = 0;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        int count = 0 ;
        foreach (string s in sa)
        {
            {
                try
                {
                    bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(s);//Its will raise an error OutOf Memory
                    if (bitmap != null)
                    {
                        count = bitmap.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
                        frame += count;
                        bitmap = null;
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not TIFF image file. please select the folder in which tif file is available", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        cntval.Text = frame.ToString();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        return 1;

    }
```

On **path** of function set the array of all the image file

```
Error:OutOfMemory
```

Comment: `string[] sa = path;` this assignment is not needed at all.

Comment: The Bitmap class is the singular class in the .NET Framework that stops you from ignoring IDisposable.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 using (bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(s))
                        {

                               ...                          
                        }
```

Comment: This will call the Dispose-method, telling your image from releasing any memory it holds when it goes out of scope (leaves the using scope).